# Jupyter Notebook: search text and go to cell.

Tags: navigation, jupyter-notebook

When selecting all cells, the `F` keyboard shortcut opens the "Find and Replace" interface, where I can see all cells for my search expression, and potentially replace that expression.

However I haven't found a way to go to these cells. This is specifically problematic since my browser don't detect these cells when using the "collapsing Header" extension.

[Find and Replace Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llglN.png)

Comment: Since there was no satisfactory answer and this is an old question I have [re-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116178/) it.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works for me.

Comment: And up and down arrows on emerged small window enable navigating along.

Comment: I only press "ctrl" + "F".

Comment: This does not work if using the "collapsing header" or "code folding" jupyter notebook extensions, which is the issue the OP raised.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution by @brian-tompsett-汤莱恩 surprisingly works also with collapsible_headings nbextension to find an occurence, but one cannot navigate to the cell. (sorry for new answer, i have no reputation)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31840331)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @biban is right. However, as the comment to @brian-tompsett-汤莱恩 referred, we only need press "ctrl" + "F". It can find the context and go to it. Sorry for not upvoting and commenting the above two answers, I don't have reputation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35336845)