# Find and go-to text when using nbextensions which hide code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

This is a duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024547) 3-year-old question, which does not have a satisfactory solution.

The question is about finding and going to text across all cells of a Jupyter Notebook when using nbextensions such as *Collapsible Headings* or *Codefolding*.

For all cells under a collapsed heading and for folded code, the browser's `Ctrl + F` does not work.

The Jupyter Notebook's command `F` allows you to "Find and replace" text across all cells, as below:

[image]

However, it does not allow **going** to the location of each finding. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `nbscan` shows cells with requested text but there is no way to automatically go to them, unfortunately.